# Пишет PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied( то есть доступ запрещён), но на форумах пишут, что проблема в другом

Tags: python

```
import os
import time 
import shutil

# получение имени папки(время создания):
time_s = time.time() # получение времени с начала эпохи в секундах
time_y = time.ctime(time_s) # преобразование секунд в нормальное время

# замена недопустимых символов
time_y = time_y.replace(" ", "_") 
time_y = time_y.replace(":", ".") 

# создание папки
directory = os.getcwd() # получаем местоположение программы
dir_res = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), time_y) #создание правильного пути к папке с программой
os.mkdir(dir_res) # создание папки

# сбор имён требуемых для архивации файлов
b = 1
i = 1
while i != 0:
    a = str(input("Введите директорию копирования " + str(b) + ": "))
    b+=1

    #остановка сбора
    if a == "Всё":
        break

    #копирование файлов в нужную папку
    shutil.copy2(a, dir_res)

close = str(input("Нажмите любую кнопку для завершения..."))
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Введите директорию копирования 1: E:\CFG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\Desktop\second.py", line 30, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(a, dir_res)
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 434, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\CFG'
```

Из-за последней строки выдаёт ошибку. В чём проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А точно есть права на выходной каталог?

Comment: Я пробовал менять папки, и папку копирования ставить в ту же директорию, не помогает, я хотел попробовать через shutil.copystat, но не совсем много инфы нашёл на эту операцию